# API Gateway + AWS SageMaker - AWS ARN for integration contains invalid action for integration with sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

As mentioned in step-3 of [this blog by AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/creating-a-machine-learning-powered-rest-api-with-amazon-api-gateway-mapping-templates-and-amazon-sagemaker/), I have created a role to invoke sagemaker endpoint. But, when I deploy the API to a stage, I get "AWS ARN for integration contains invalid action" and I can't deploy the stage.
[image]

blog suggested to select API Gateway under services and to keep on next, but didn't mention which policy will be attached. and also that another inline policy to invoke a specific sagemaker endpoint to be created and attached.
[image]

and as mentioned in [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integration-request-basic-setup.html):

> It must also have API Gateway declared (in the role's trust
> relationship) as a trusted entity to assume the role.

my role also have the trust-relationshp:
[image]

What's missing in my role that led to the error?

Comment: What option did you choose for "Action Type" (Use Action Name or Use Path Override) for your GET Method? You did this under Step 4 "Creating a Get Method" in your blog post.

Comment: i chose post method. so, api gateway receives post and a post request to sagemaker too. the action type i chose is "use path override".

Comment: I added an answer with this suggestion now, can be worth double checking that you haven't picked "Use Action Name" in some other method you have. Otherwise the answer might help someone else. Leaving out the "Action" is a reason for this error and it has nothing to do with policys or permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in all your API methods that you haven't specified "Use Action Name" for any integration request, and then left the "Action" field blank. If you do the "AWS ARN for integration contains invalid action" error message will be shown.

[image: action type choice]